# how do i make a seven segment digit clock animation?

Tags: animation

I was modelling a sci-fi style digital clock, and when finished, I realized that I had no idea how to make the animation.

I made the numbers, but I cannot figure out a simple way to make it work.

[image]

I thought I could make all the ten numbers and then hide and unhide them every second, but takes too long.

Does someone have any idea? can someone suggest me a easier way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: You could try making all the numbers 0-9 in a frame range that won't be rendered. Then just copy them over from the dopesheet when you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some python code can do that for you:D**

1. Create two text objects and name them 'hour' and 'minute' respectively
2. Run scripts below.
3. Scraping the Timeline and you now have a digit clock animation. (Choose a digital font if you like.)

scripts:

```
import bpy


def update(self):
    frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

    minute = bpy.data.objects['minute']
    hour = bpy.data.objects['hour']

    hour.data.body = str(int(frame/60) % 24) + ' :'
    minute.data.body = str(frame % 60)


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(update)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(update)


register()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh what a nice answer :). I'm definitely going to use this in the near future :).

Comment: Glad you like it:)

Comment: thank you very much for giving me an answer that soon! i really wasn't expecting that. however, probabliy because i'm a beginner and i'm not good at scripting, the script that you sent me doesn't work. i tried to replicate your screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGXZ3TbQrBL1gkX8DmXtjNPu8Sw_AvR3/view?usp=sharing                             can you help me one more time? i wuold really appreciate that

Comment: @federico Access the driver need a permission. I've sent the request.

Comment: @federico It looks like you don't run the scripts. Button is in the topbar of text editor. Run scripts first. Then scraping the Timeline.

Comment: Ahhh I missed that little detail. Thank you!